# cordova app showing issue after ios 10 upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode8, ios10

Recently I updated my Cordova app with ios 10 sdk. I am using xcode 8.1 and cordova 6.4.0

The following error shows while trying to run on emulator

```
2016-11-19 14:47:31.937441 Myapp[4876:267791] [Common] _BSMachError: port 9a03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2016-11-19 14:47:31.937868 Myapp[4876:267791] [Common] _BSMachError: port 9a03; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"
```

I have seen some solutions on stackoverflow. But they do not solve the issue.